# ASP.net - What is the best way to pass a list from code behind to java script?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In javascript, I want to compare the selected value from a dropdown list to a list of values from my C# code behind. I've tried passing a string list through a HiddenField, but I can't get past the problem of 'Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference'.

Looking around Stackoverflow and elsewhere I've tried many variations of the following code but the 'split error' has me stymied.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldList" runat="server" />

//Code behind:
HiddenFieldList.Value = String.Join(",", ValuesList);

//javascript
var CSVList = document.getElementById("HiddenFieldList").value;
var HFList = [];
HFList = this.CSVList.split(',');

// hoping to get to here...
for(i = 0; i < HFList.length; i++) 
{
   if (DDL == HFList[i])
   {
       do stuff ;
       break ;
    }
 }
```

Or...instead of assigning a string list to my hidden field should I pass an array?? 
Fwiw - the project is not MVC.

Edit: My code behind list is derived from values in a datatable column.

Comment: On your ASP.NET page, at the server side, just generate a bunch of text that begins with `<script>` ends with `</script>` and has `var theArray = [...]`' inside. At the client side you'll end up with `theArray` as a local variable.

Comment: Please see my edit - bottom line.

Comment: please add your razor markup

Comment: Please see my edits

Comment: Change your code this.CSVList.split(‘,’) to CSVList.split just remove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line of code

```
HFList = this.CSVList.split(',');
```

to

```
HFList = CSVList.split(',');
```

because CSVList is local variable.

Comment: It now works as expected. What is frustrating is that I'd previously tried the same text as you suggested - and still received the error. Thank you for your time.